# TcpClient not working with Xamarin.Forms when using cellular data

Tags: c#, xamarin, tcpclient

I have an application that is using TcpClient to send a byte array over the internet. When I use Wi-Fi on the Android smartphone I am using, it works fine and connects with the receiving server, but when I switch to data, it fails to connect to the receiving server. What am I doing wrong? Is there a special permission I need to give my app?

Comment: It doesn't seem like I have IPv6, and yes, it is accessible. It seems to work and receive data when my phone is on WiFi. I also used an open port check tool to check the port the app is running on.

Comment: I just tried the port checker while connected to the same network the server is on.

Comment: Ah sorry I was using a port checking website. If I use a port checking tool based on my cellular device's network, and I am on cellular data, it doesn't seem to be able to access the port.

Comment: Do you actually have a "publicly" accessible hostname/ip address? Might be a server on a local network with a private IP address, but your Internet router would have to have port forwarding setup and thus you would connect to the *public* IP of Internet router or have your local server assigned a public ip address (& hostname) and setup in your router's DMZ zone.

Comment: Yeah, I'm connecting using the public IP, and I have the port forwarded through my router.

Comment: Via that port check app in your app, are you using an IPv4 address or an IPv6 address? (your ISP/router should have a IPv6 address assigned...) i.e. some cellular  networks only provide IPv6 via their cellular data connection

Comment: Seems like I only have IPv4 on my home/server netowork.